# express js cannot GET /page

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am very stuck with a routing error on express.js. I am using jade to render my page views. I have read all the docs and refactored many times to no avail.

This is the plain contents of the link that is pointing to the '/sell' route.

**index.jade**

```
include layout
html
  button.btn.btn-primary(type='submit', href='/sell') Add Item
```

When clicking this button the browser returns the following as a 404:

> Cannot GET /sell

The problem here is that all other routes work correctly, if you are to modify the above href to other pages i.e. '/' , '/sign_in', etc no error occurs. The problem appears to be isolated to the '/sell' route.

The controller with the '/sell' route is below:

**server.js**

```
var dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.load();
var session = require('express-session')
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
var async = require('async');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var flash = require('express-flash');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var root  = __dirname;
var path = require('path');
var User = require('./models/user');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var errorHelper = require('mongoose-error-helper').errorHelper;
var validator = require('validator');
var Item = require("./models/item")

var username, email, password, owner, product_name, condition, details, price;

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_CONGO_DEV);

// Middleware
app.set('views', 'app/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session( {
  secret: 'session secret key',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));
app.use(flash());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Routing

app.get('/', function(req,res) {
    res.render('index', {
    title: 'Congo',
    message: 'Congo',
    user: req.user
  });
});

app.get('/sell', function(req,res) {
    res.render('item', {
    title: 'Congo - Sell',
    message: 'Sell',
    user: req.user
  });
});

app.get('/sign_in', function(req,res) {
    res.render('sign_in', {
    title: 'Congo',
    message: 'sign in motherfucker',
    user: req.user
  });
});

app.post('/sign_in', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) return next(err)
    if (!user) {
      req.flash('error', 'Incorrect login details');
      return res.redirect('/sign_in')
    };
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      res.
      return res.redirect('/');
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});

app.get('/sign_up', function(req, res) {
  res.render('sign_up', {
    title: 'Congo',
    message: 'sign up',
    user: req.user
  });
});

app.post('/sign_up', function(req, res) {
  var user = new User({
      username: req.body.username,
      email: req.body.email,
      password: req.body.password
    });
  if (req.body.confirm != req.body.password) {
    req.flash('error', 'Password do not match')
    res.redirect('/sign_up')
  };
  else if (validator.isEmail(req.body.email) === false) {
    req.flash('error', 'Invalid email address')
    res.redirect('/sign_up')
  };
  else {
  user.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {
    req.flash('error', 'Email already in use')
    res.redirect('/sign_up')
    } else {
        req.logIn(user, function(err) {
        res.redirect('/');
      });
      }
    });
  };
});

app.get('/logout', function(req, res){
  req.logout();
  res.redirect('/');
});

app.get('/forgot', function(req, res) {
  res.render('forgot', {
    user: req.user,
    message: 'you wally'
  });
});

app.get('/profile', function(req, res) {
  res.render('profile', {
    user: req.user,
    message: 'User profile'
  });
});

app.post('/forgot', function(req, res, next) {
  async.waterfall([
    function(done) {
      crypto.randomBytes(20, function(err, buf) {
        var token = buf.toString('hex');
        done(err, token);
      });
    },
    function(token, done) {
      User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, function(err, user) {
        if (!user) {
          req.flash('error', 'No account with that email address exists.');
          return res.redirect('/forgot');
        };

        user.resetPasswordToken = token;
        user.resetPasswordExpires = Date.now() + 3600000; // 1 hour

        user.save(function(err) {
          done(err, token, user);
        });
      });
    },
    function(token, user, done) {
      var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport('SMTP', {
        service: 'Gmail',
        auth: {
          user: 'harryandrew.dix@gmail.com',
          pass: process.env.GMAIL_PASS
        };
      });
      var mailOptions = {
        to: user.email,
        from: 'passwordreset@demo.com',
        subject: 'Node.js Password Reset',
        text: 'You are receiving this because you (or someone else) have requested the reset of the password for your account.\n\n' +
          'Please click on the following link, or paste this into your browser to complete the process:\n\n' +
          'http://' + req.headers.host + '/reset/' + token + '\n\n' +
          'If you did not request this, please ignore this email and your password will remain unchanged.\n'
      };
      smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err) {
        req.flash('info', 'An e-mail has been sent to ' + user.email + ' with further instructions.');
        done(err, 'done');
      });
    };
  ], function(err) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.redirect('/forgot');
  });
});

app.get('/reset/:token', function(req,res) {
  User.findOne({resetPasswordToken: req.params.token, resetPasswordExpires: { $gt: Date.now()}}, function(err,user) {
    if (!user) {
      req.flash('error', 'Password reset token invalid or expired.');
      return res.redirect('/forgot');
    }
    res.render('reset', {
      user: req.user,
      message: 'reset dem pass'
    });
  });
});

app.post('/reset/:token', function(req, res) {
  async.waterfall([
    function(done) {
      User.findOne({ resetPasswordToken: req.params.token, resetPasswordExpires: { $gt: Date.now() } }, function(err, user) {
        if (!user) {
          req.flash('error', 'Password reset token is invalid or has expired.');
          return res.redirect('back');
        };

        user.password = req.body.password;
        user.resetPasswordToken = undefined;
        user.resetPasswordExpires = undefined;

        user.save(function(err) {
          req.logIn(user, function(err) {
            done(err, user);
          });
        });
      });
    },
    function(user, done) {
      var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport('SMTP', {
        service: 'Gmail',
        auth: {
          user: 'harryandrew.dix@gmail.com',
          pass: process.env.GMAIL_PASS
        };
      });
      var mailOptions = {
        to: user.email,
        from: 'passwordreset@demo.com',
        subject: 'Your password has been changed',
        text: 'Hello,\n\n' +
          'This is a confirmation that the password for your account ' + user.email + ' has just been changed.\n'
      };
      smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err) {
        req.flash('success', 'Success! Your password has been changed.');
        done(err);
      });
    };
  ], function(err) {
    res.redirect('/');
  });
});

// app.post('/add_item', function(req, res) {
//   var item = new Item({
//       owner: req.user.id,
//       product_name: req.body.product_name,
//       condition: req.body.condition,
//       details: req.body.details,
//       price: req.body.price
//   });
//   item.save(function(err) {
//     if (err) {
//       req.flash('error', 'Something went wrong, make sure you are signed in.')
//         res.redirect('/add_item');
//     } else {
//       req.logIn(item, function(err) {
//         res.redirect('/user_profile');
//       });
//     };
//   });
// });

var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s',host,port);
});
```

**item.jade**

```
include layout
html
  block content
    form(method='POST')
        legend(style='font-family: Raleway; font-size: 30px;') Item Details
      .form-group
        label(for='product_name') Product Name
        input.form-control(type='text', name='product_name', placeholder='include product name, brand, condition, colour etc.', required autofocus)
      .form-group
        label(for='condition') Condition
        input.form-control(type='text', name='condition', placeholder='e.g. New, Used', required)
      .form-group
        label(for='image') Image
        input.form-control(type='file', name='image')
      .form-group
        label(for='details') Details
        textarea.form-control(name='details', cols='40', rows='5')
      .form-group
        label(for='price') Price
      .input-group
        .input-group-addon £
        input.form-control(type='text', placeholder='Amount', required)
        .input-group-addon .00
      br
      br
      button#btnSubmit.btn.btn-primary(type='submit') Post Item
```

Comment: do you have jade file called `item.jade`?

Comment: yes - see addition above

Comment: I'm not sure but I think there must be middleware that denies routing to /sell route. Check passport settings or etc.

Comment: will check and get back

Comment: Are all of your views located within the directory `app/views`? What about changing your views to be `app.use('views', path.join(root, 'app/views'));`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's acting as form post and tries to reach  app.post('/sell')
Change it:

```
button.btn.btn-primary(type='submit', href='/sell') Add Item
```

to:

```
a.btn.btn-primary(href='/sell') Add Item
```

also remove some parts of middleware and keep only these lines:

```
app.set('views', 'app/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.use(logger('dev'));
```

and then navigate in Your browser to  /sell route, check if it's working.
if Yes - so problem with one of middlewares that we have deleted to check.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a logger middleware and see what error the server gives when you try to go to that route. Another thing to try would be to rename the sell route and see if that works. That could indicate a conflict with another one of your routes, although it's not clear where this would be from looking at your code.

Comment: for example I have just changed the name of the routing to '/bonzai', then 'cannot GET /bonzai' is returned

Comment: Try doing a console.log from the top of the /sell route handler to see if it's being hit at all.

Comment: Thanks Michael, the console.log() just pulls back a 404; http://tinyurl.com/os655u7

Comment: if you do console.log('hello'), does it get printed in the console where you're running express? You might also comment out the rest of the handler and replace it with: res.send('Hello World!');

Comment: no it does not, the same 404, express is not finding the route

Comment: oh okay.. yeah I guess it's not getting hit at all. This is a stretch, but there might be a hidden character in the code somewhere.. Try deleting the code for the /sell handler, and type it in again. Something like this: app.get('/sell', function(req,res) {  res.send('Hello World'); });